# How do I insert an array, generated in a function, into the body of the HTML?

Tags: jquery, html

How do I insert the array generated by this function...

```
<script>
    function generate_array() {
        var items = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
        // TODO: Insert the array of items into the form below.
    }
</script>
```

... into the area that currently says *ARRAY_OF_ITEMS*...

```
...
<body>
...
    <form id="sortable_list" action="/cgi-bin/test" method="post">
        <ul id="sortable">
            <li id="1">item1</li>
            <li id="2">item2</li>
            <li id="3">item3</li>
            <li id="4">item4</li>
        </ul>
        <input type="hidden" name="page"   value="items"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_order"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="order"  value="ARRAY_OF_ITEMS"/>
        <input type="submit" value="save" onclick="generate_array()"/>
    </form>
...
</body>
```

... so if the item array variable is `4,2,1,3` when the form is submitted the POST string sent would be `page=items&action=save_order&order=4,2,1,3`.

Assume the page has other forms so an answer needs to specifically target that area. I'm generating the HTML so adding extra attributes is okay if an answer requires it.

Comment: $("[name='order']", $("#sortable_list")).val (items);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$("[name='order']", $("#sortable_list")).val (items);`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to target your input using jQuery's [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) and then set the value like this:

```
$('#sortable_list [name="order"]').val(items);
```

You can expand the snippet below if you want to see it in action.

```js
$(function() {
  let items = "4,2,1,3";
  $('#sortable_list [name="order"]').val(items);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sortable_list" action="/cgi-bin/test" method="post">
  <ul id="sortable">
    <li id="1">item1</li>
    <li id="2">item2</li>
    <li id="3">item3</li>
    <li id="4">item4</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="hidden" name="page" value="items" />
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_order" />
  <input type="input" name="order" value="ARRAY_OF_ITEMS" />
  <input type="submit" value="save" onclick="generate_array()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. The ARRAY_OF_ITEMS placeholder string is still not being replaced. The POST string sent is `page=items&action=save_order&order=ARRAY_OF_ITEMS`

Comment: @x-x gah sorry, that's what I get when I try to answer from my phone. I updated the answer and it will work now.